# Angular 2+ multiple HTML template for one component

Tags: html, angular, components

I have the following scenario. I am writing a complex component that is using three-js:

[image]

The component manages complex mouse interactions and updates other elements in the DOM using two-ways data binding: variables, JSON objects, mouse interactions, etc.

I start using the component in few part of my application but I needed to substantially modified the threed-viewer.html so I made a copy of the whole component ending up having duplicates that are hard to maintain.

All flavours of the component share 80% of the javascript code and bindings but they have substantial UI differences. So I had the though of create different 3 basic component (minimal javascript code) that I can inject into the threed-viewer.html using a selector and a variable to decide which template to load:

[image]

this does not compile as the html files have all the variables and bindings from the original components but they are not present in the typescript files.
Another solution could be to have a single html managed via ngIf but it will result in a long, messy, difficult to manage file. Is this the only option I have in Angular. Any other idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a shared service and then add three different components but js code won't be duplicated as it will be in the service.
Use two way bindings in all 3 components using the service variables, functions and objects

Answer (score 0):

I have did long time ago - the pages and article editor. Two different templates, same code.

I used articles component as "parent", and extended it to news editor.

Looks like this:

```
@Component({template: 'blah blah blah'}) export class parent {}
@Component({template: 'blah2 blah2 blah2'}) export class child extends parent {}
```

Hopefully this is the solution you were looking for.
Two different components, two templates, one code.
Of course, you can have the "parent" abstract class for both where you can save all methods you need.

It's OOP baby ;)